# $\Delta \vec{v}=0$ implies $\nabla\cdot \vec{v}=\nabla\times \vec{v}=0$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

> \begin{align}
> \Delta\overrightarrow{v}&=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{v})-\nabla\times(\nabla\times\overrightarrow{v})\\
> \nabla\cdot(\overrightarrow{v}\times\overrightarrow{w})&=\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\nabla\times\overrightarrow{v}-\overrightarrow{v}\cdot\nabla\times\overrightarrow{w}\\
> \nabla\cdot(f\overrightarrow{v})&=(\nabla f)\cdot\overrightarrow{v}+f\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{v}
> \end{align}
>   Suppose $\overrightarrow{v}$ satisfies $\Delta\overrightarrow{v}=0$
>   and that $\overrightarrow{v}$ vanishes outside some bounded region $V \subset \Bbb R^3$.
>   Show that $\nabla\times\overrightarrow{v}=0$ and $\nabla\cdot\overrightarrow{v}=0$. (Hint: Integrate $\overrightarrow{v}\Delta \overrightarrow{v}$ over a suitable region. You will need to make use of the divergence theorem.)

I started by integrating the hint, then using the first identity for $\Delta\overrightarrow{v}$, then separated the integral.
I tried to get it into the form for Gauss theorem, and know that the dot product is commutative so I tried that, but neither of the integrals that I separated the original one from can be solved with Gauss theorem.

I feel that I am very far off the solution, any hints as to the next step would be greatly appreciated. The original document is linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSNm.png) in case that would be easier to read.
Thanks in advance for the help.
I am new to math.stackexchange, please let me know if I make any mistakes with inputting my question.

Comment: You might need to edit that question.

Comment: I've adjusted your question's Mathjax a bit, and I've moved the picture to a link so that it all reads better. On a mathematical level, it's worth noting that $\Delta$ in the above question is necessarily the _vector_ Laplacian rather than the _scalar_ Laplacian.

Comment: $\Delta \vec v =\nabla^2 \vec v$, right?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on that equality. How can the divergence be equal to the curl? One is a scalar and one is vector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the statement $\nabla \cdot \vec v = \nabla \times \vec v = 0$ is a minor abuse of notation, since as pointed out in the comments, $\nabla \cdot \vec v$ is a scalar but $\nabla \times \vec v$ is a vector.  Furthermore, I assume that $\vec v$ is a $C^2$ vector field on $\Bbb R^3$, so that all the derivatives make sense.

These things being said, here is a proof which, though not directly employing the given hint, goes a little further than requested and shows that $\vec v = 0$ identically, from which the required results immediately and trivially follow.

By $\Delta$ we mean $\nabla^2$, and so $\Delta \vec v = \nabla^2 \vec v$, where by $\nabla^2 \vec v$ we mean, in a global Cartesian coordinate system, that $\nabla^2$ is to be applied to each component of $\vec v$ separately, so that taking

$\vec v = (v_1, v_2, v_3) \tag{1}$

we have

$\nabla^2 \vec v = (\nabla^2 v_1, \nabla^2 v_2, \nabla^2 v_3). \tag{2}$

(2) may also be directly validated by working through our OP Dan Smith's given equation

$\nabla^2 \vec v = \Delta \vec v = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \vec v) - \nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec v) \tag{3}$

in Cartesian coordinates, a straightforward task requiring mainly careful bookkeeping of indices:

$\nabla \times \vec v = (v_{3, 2} - v_{2, 3}, v_{1, 3} - v_{3, 1}, v_{2, 1} - v_{1, 2}) \tag{4}$

where we have used the notation

$v_{1, 2} = \dfrac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2} \tag{5}$

and so forth, where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ are the coordinates on $\Bbb R^3$.  From (4) it follows that the $1$-component of $\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec v)$ is

$(\nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec v))_1 = v_{2, 12} - v_{1, 22} - v_{1, 33} + v_{3, 13}, \tag{6}$

and the $1$-component of $\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec v)$ is

$(\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec v))_1 = v_{1, 11} + v_{2, 21} + v_{3, 31}; \tag{7}$

we see from (6) and (7) that

$(\nabla(\nabla \cdot \vec v) - \nabla \times (\nabla \times \vec v))_1 = v_{1, 11} + v_{1, 22} + v_{1, 33}, \tag{8}$

and the corresponding results hold for the $2$ and $3$ components, so

$\nabla^2 \vec v = \Delta \vec v = (\nabla^2 v_1, \nabla^2 v_2, \nabla^2 v_3) \tag{9}$

as claimed.  It follows then from $\Delta \vec v = 0$ that $\nabla^2 v_i = 0$ for $1 \le i \le 3$; each component of $\vec v$ is a harmonic function on $\Bbb R^3$.  But a harmonic function which vanishes outside of a bounded set such as $V$ must be identically zero; this follows from the [mean value property of harmonic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) $u$, which in the present circumstances states that for $p \in \Bbb R^3$

$u(p) = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi R^2}\int_{\partial B(p, R)} u dS, \tag{10}$

where $B(p, R)$ is the ball of radius $R$ centered at $p$, and $dS$ is the surface area measure on the sphere bounding said ball.  By taking $R$ sufficiently large for any particular $p$, we see that the integral in (10) must vanish if $u$ vanishes outside of some bounded set $V$; $u = 0$ identically on a sufficiently large sphere.  Thus we see that $\vec v = 0$ everywhere, whence in particular $\nabla \cdot \vec v$ and $\nabla \times \vec v = 0$ as well.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Here are some signposts towards the solution. First, here are two applications of the two 'product rule' vector identities given above, specifically for the cases $\vec{w}=\nabla\times\vec{v}$ and $f=\nabla\cdot\vec{v}$:

\begin{align}
\vec{v}\cdot(\nabla\times (\nabla\times\vec{v}))
&=-\nabla\cdot(\vec{v}\times(\nabla\times\vec{v}))+(\nabla\times \vec{v})^2\\
\\
\vec{v}\cdot\nabla(\nabla\cdot\vec{v})
&=\nabla\cdot(\vec{v}\;(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}))-(\nabla\cdot\vec{v})^2
\end{align}
That, along with the first identity for the vector Laplacian of $\vec{v}$, is enough to get to the application of the Divergence Theorem. What remains is the choice of region $R$;  for that you should think carefully about the bounded region $V$.